# Sets in list self-unite for some reason

Tags: python, list, if-statement, set, union

I'm trying to program the Kruskal algorithm for minimal weight tree in Python, where the weighted edges are represented as a list of tuples ({i,j},w), where {i,j} is the edge, and w is the weight. But after going through an if (which verifies its connection) the first edge turns into the set of nodes.
I placed some prints to discover where did it changed, here what I tried:

```
import itertools
import random

def conexo(X,A):
  #X : set of nodes
  #A : list of edges {i,j}
  if set().union(*A)!=X: #if there are isolated nodes
    return False
  else:
    G={i:set().union(*[a for a in A if i in a])-{i} for i in X} #{node: successors set}
    C=A[0] #connected nodes
    for i in G: #eliminate C from the successors set
      G[i]-=C

    while True:
      suc=list(set().union(*[G[i] for i in C])) #successors list
      if suc==list(): break #if there are no more successors, the loop finishes
      j=suc[0] #chooses a successor
      C|={j} #adds j to the set of connected nodes
      for i in G: #takes off j from the successors sets
          G[i]-={j}
    if C==X: #if al nodes are connected
      return True
    else:
      return False

def kruskal(X,G):
  #X : set of nodes
  #G : list of weighted edges ({i,j},p)
  print('G',G)
  G.sort(key=lambda tup : tup[1])
  print('G',G)
  A=[g[0] for g in G]
  if conexo(X,A): #THE BREAKING POINT OF THE PROBLEM
    print('G',G)
    tree=[G[0]]
    aris=[G[0][0]]
    for i in range(1,len(G)):
      if not conciclo(aris+[G[i][0]]):
        tree.append(G[i])
        aris.append(G[i][0])
      if len(tree)==len(X)-1:
        break
    return tree
  else:
    return 'disconex'
```

input:

```
X={i for i in range(1,5)}
g=[({1,2},1),({1,3},1),({2,4},1),({2,3},5)]
print(kruskal(X,g))
```

expected:

```
G [({1, 2}, 1), ({1, 3}, 1), ({2, 4}, 1), ({2, 3}, 5)]
G [({1, 2}, 1), ({1, 3}, 1), ({2, 4}, 1), ({2, 3}, 5)]
G [({1, 2}, 1), ({1, 3}, 1), ({2, 4}, 1), ({2, 3}, 5)]
[({1, 2}, 1), ({1, 3}, 1), ({2, 4}, 1)]
```

actual output:

```
G [({1, 2}, 1), ({1, 3}, 1), ({2, 4}, 1), ({2, 3}, 5)]
G [({1, 2}, 1), ({1, 3}, 1), ({2, 4}, 1), ({2, 3}, 5)]
G [({1, 2, 3, 4}, 1), ({1, 3}, 1), ({2, 4}, 1), ({2, 3}, 5)]
[({1, 2, 3, 4}, 1), ({1, 3}, 1), ({2, 4}, 1)]
```

Comment: Do you understand this line? `G={i:set().union(*[a for a in A if i in a])-{i} for i in X}` I don't.

Comment: `conciclo` is not defined.  what is this ?

Comment: @mkrieger1,  it is difficult to read. sometimes squeezing everything on one line makes debugging / readability harder.

Comment: @D.L I know, that's what I meant to say.

Answer (score 1):

Python is pass by reference, meaning that variable assignments and function arguments don't create a copy of the objects, so any modifications to the objects are reflected on the outside. In you case, this happens through `A`, from which you assign `A[0]` to `C`, which you then modify in the line `C|={j}`.

This can for example be fixed by explictly creating a copy of `A[0]` when assigning it to `C`:

```
    # ...
    G={i:set().union(*[a for a in A if i in a])-{i} for i in X} #{node: successors set}
    C=set(A[0]) #connected nodes
    for i in G: #eliminate C from the successors set
      G[i]-=C
    # ...
```

Comment: omg thank you very much, you saved my project